# text in Textlabel is reset to first value after i go back and again into this view controller....how can i save it?

Tags: uitableview, tableview, swift4, textlabel

I'm new in programming and want to try some things. So I have two view controllers. The first one has a button, which brings me to the second view controller, when tapped. In the second view controller, I have a table view with a prototype cell. In my class tableViewCell I define this cell and there are also two functions for - button and a + button. So the problem is, the functions work and set the value in a label of the cell like a stepper. But when I go back to my first view controller and then again into the second view controller, the value of the label is again 1. So How can I save the tapped value for this label? 
You can see the code for my cell here:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol FridgeListTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func cellDecreaseButtontapped(_ sender: FridgeListTableViewCell)
    func cellIncreasedButtontapped(_ sender: FridgeListTableViewCell)
}

class FridgeListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var wareLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var decreaseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var increaseButton: UIButton!

     weak var delegate: FridgeListTableViewCellDelegate?


    @IBAction func decreaseTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let counter = Int(quantityLabel.text!)
        let newCounter = counter! - 1
        let newCounterString = String(newCounter)
        quantityLabel.text = newCounterString

        delegate?.cellDecreaseButtontapped(self)
    }

    @IBAction func increaseTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let counter = Int(quantityLabel.text!)
        let newCounter = counter! + 1
        let newCounterString = String(newCounter)
        quantityLabel.text = newCounterString

        delegate?.cellIncreasedButtontapped(self)
    }



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and the part of my second view controller, where I call this functions:

```
 func cellDecreaseButtontapped(_ sender: FridgeListTableViewCell) {
    guard let tappedIndexPath = fridgeList.indexPath(for: sender) else { return }
    print("Decrease", sender, tappedIndexPath)
}
func cellIncreasedButtontapped(_ sender: FridgeListTableViewCell) {
    guard let tappedIndexPath = fridgeList.indexPath(for: sender) else { return }
    print("Increase", sender, tappedIndexPath)
}
```

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Save the value in the model, the data source array of the table view.

Comment: so you mean using core data, where i also save the name of the cell?

Comment: As you have the index path you have the data source item. Add a property (`counter` or whatever) and save the value there.

Comment: ok perhaps I'm to dump for this, but how can i connect the property then with the index path? sorry...

Comment: You are talking about Core Data, so you might have an array of `NSManagedObject` instances as data source. In the `NSManagedObject` class add the property (actually *attribute*) to keep the counter value. Then update the counter value and save the context.

Comment: @vadian sorry...it took awhile...but now it is working. learning by doing... :D